how to find non responsive binaries using `ps`
I want to run a command using ps to find non responsive binaries.
This stack question has a response which I've tried to implement, but I am getting odd results from it.
ps aux | awk -F' ' '{ if ( $8="D" )  print $0 }'
This is supposed to return only the lines from ps where column 8 has the letters "D". What I am seeing is that it's replacing column 8 with the letter D instead.
I have tried on zsh and bash, using gawk instead of awk, and getting the same result. What is wrong with this command?
I am interested in why it's failing.

The operator for equality is a double equal sign. A single equal sign is an assignment.
 ps aux | awk -F' ' '{ if ( $8=="D" )  print $0 }'

The command will never return any output on a Mac, because there is no status D.

Also, ps only shows binaries unresponsive (stuck) on Unix level, not GUI applications which are just too busy to process input events.

I edited the title to add binaries. What prompted this quest was the family binary which keeps locking up. I want to be notified so I can force close it. /System/Library/CoreServices/Family.app/Contents/MacOS/Family

@Linc-D. Are you the original and outstanding Linc Davis from the Apple forums of yesteryear?

Guilty as charged. Best to post another question with more details of the real problem, and without prejudging how to solve it.

@LincD. We are supposed to ask one question at a time and attempt a solution before coming here.

@john The main problem here is that the question title asks something different than the question body (who mainly is about getting a code snippet to work which already was wrong in the Unix.SE post).

@LincD. question posted: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/475134/family-process-is-often-non-responsive-many-faults-in-console-app
