Family process is often non responsive many faults in Console.app
The Family process (/System/Library/CoreServices/Family.app/Contents/MacOS/Family) is hanging randomly on macOS. When this happens Screen Time settings fail to sync from iPhone to iMac, Find My struggles to locate devices, and cpu begins to overheat. I have been on the phone and screen shared with Apple Tier 1 with no resolution.
There are multiple questions on Apple community, reddit, and other forums trying to resolve this issue. AFAIK none have been successful.
One suggestion was adding /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/imagent.app as an Allow rule in Network Firewall ( OR even just turning off the Firewall in Network settings ) to test if that solved this issue.
So far (after 12 hours of monitoring Activity Monitor) it seems to have prevented the Family binary getting stuck in a (Non Responsive) state but hundreds of errors in Console.app suggests the issue is still present.
With Firewall off I see hundreds of console faults for the Family process:
43315   fault   12:26:52.972217-0500    Family  CoreData: Unable to create token NSXPCConnection.  NSXPCStoreServerEndpointFactory 0x7f8e89122f10 -newEndpoint returned nil

Other curious entries:
1174    fault   12:29:47.235445-0500    UIKitSystem container_query_get_single_result: client is not entitled
1113    fault   12:34:14.299396-0500    imagent Couldn't write values for keys (
    CheckSensitivePhotosAnalytics
) in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x7fa770925990> (Domain: com.apple.messages.commsafety, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: No): setting these preferences requires user-preference-write or file-write-data sandbox access
164 fault   12:34:22.125092-0500    apsd    Peer connection [pid=1051] lacks APSConnectionInitiateEntitlement
46757   fault   12:34:30.890039-0500    com.apple.WebKit.WebContent checkinWithServer Failed bootstrap_lookup2 for name of coreservicesd, kern_return_t=#1100/0x44c Permission denied name=com.apple.CoreServices.coreservicesd

Why is this process hanging?


If turning off the Firewall solves the problem, why not just leave it off? Unless you're doing something very unusual, it serves no purpose. Scary log messages are not a problem in themselves. Thousands of them are generated every hour on all Macs.

The "why" may be difficult to answer (even though it seems to be network-related). But can you run ps aux | grep -i family the next time it is stuck and add the result to the question? It might offer a clue.
